# How to upload profile picture and show instance using asp.net mvc5?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I know this is may be an old question.Sorry for that.I search Google but can't find any good link.In my asp.net mvc5 application,i have a user profile form.1)I want user can upload there profile picture and show instance preview.but when user upload picture the form will not submit.2)After picture instance show and other field complete,When user click submit button then the data will be insert in to database with picture information.i can do the part 2.but number 1 : upload and instance show,i am confuse how can i do that(easy way).Thanks

Comment: Something like this: http://demo.phpgang.com/jquery-show-image-thumbnail-before-upload/

Comment: In your controller, I would create a new instance of the profile form and have your data context return the new profile ID.
Your profile entity will remain null right now but you will have a new profile ID for the profile picture to reference when it is uploaded. 

Now; after the picture is uploaded, the user can finish the rest of the form and then you can call an update method in the repository to simply update that same profile entity that was created in the first step.

Comment: @RobertRozas Yes .....

Comment: someway, you own answer, please submit it, its help for the beginner,Thanks